# storing wildcards in variables and echoing the output of doing an ls on that variable

Tags: bash

hmm... I might have to edit this if it is not clear...

I want to be able to store "*.php" in a variable and then when I do a echo on that variable name I want the output to be the same as `ls *.php`

this is what I want and I achieve what I want, but I do not think this is best practice `echo $f` without the double quotes

```
$ echo $f
2G_3G_Overview_Dashboard_week.php 2G_3G_sgsn_attach_pdp_day.php
```

but if I do `echo "$f"` with double quotes I get the below, that is the value of the variable "*.php" and not the list of files that match *.php

```
$ echo "$f"
*.php
```

So basically I can get what I want using `echo $f` but this is not good practice as it does not have the double quotes. Can someone point me in the right direction.

here is my command log:

```
$ echo *.php
$ echo *.php
2G_3G_Overview_Dashboard_week.php 2G_3G_sgsn_attach_pdp_day.php
$
$
$ ls *.php
2G_3G_Overview_Dashboard_week.php  2G_3G_sgsn_attach_pdp_day.php
$
$
$ f=*.php
$ echo "$f"
*.php
$
$ echo $f
2G_3G_Overview_Dashboard_week.php 2G_3G_sgsn_attach_pdp_day.php
```

---

### EDIT1

I think I might need to keep the wild card outside the double quotes

```
$ f2=".php"
$ echo "$f"
*.php
$ echo "$f2"
.php
$ echo *"$f2"
2G_3G_Overview_Dashboard_week.php 2G_3G_sgsn_attach_pdp_day.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should note that when ever you surround a variable with " " , if the content of that variable contains `*` bash will not expand it. If you want file name expansion you should not quote `$f` variable. But it works in a for loop

```
# this works
f="*.php"
for i in $f;do
    echo $i
done
# this does not work
for i in "$f";do
    echo "$i"
done
# this works
for i in "$f";do
    echo $i # reads all files ones
done
```

Comment: tks you put me on right track, see edit1, I think I might need to keep the wild card outside the double quotes.

Comment: it does not format the filenames properly. it reads them as a single line